# AngularJs, DropZone.Js - Has anybody worked out a way to keep the dropzone transfers on the Angular root scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropzone.js

Would like to show the transfers from dropzone with progress in an angular view. With 2 way binding the changing progress should be easy to implement, but does anybody know how to access the transfer list in the Angular controller?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [ng-flow](https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow) for my angularjs/laravel project some time ago. It was very useful, maybe you can take a look. Is is a native directive for AngularJS so the progress is already implemented, and all the callbacks too.